# Словно - какая часть речи?

Tags: морфология

Он *словно* поставил себе задачу не возвеличивать своих заслуг.
**Словно** в данном случае частица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласна, что **это частица**. 
Хотя этот вопрос в лингвистике решается неоднозначно. Для меня **отличие союза от частицы - в его функции соединения**. В данном предложении слово "словно" такой роли не выполняет.

Сразу, конечно, возникает вопрос: а как в других случаях?

Отрывок из диссертации Пашковой Е.В.

Слова точно, словно, будто, как бы принадлежат к той группе служебных слов, которые, участвуя в смысловой организации различных синтаксических построений, способны в одних синтаксических конструкциях выполнять функцию союза, в других - частицы.
Вопрос о разграничении модально-сравнительных союзов и омонимичных им частиц является спорным. Н.А.Широкова считает, что наряду со сравнительными союзами в современном русском языке существуют сравнительные частицы, омонимичные союзам. Отличие сравнительных союзов от частиц в том, что союз сопоставляет явления, а «сравнительная частица не выполняет сопоставительной функции, она относится только к одному слову или сочетанию слов, подчеркивая условность, метафоричность обозначаемого ими признака или явления, указанного на основе сходства с каким-то иным, не названным в речи»

Comment: "Сравнительная частица не выполняет сопоставительной функции, она относится только к одному слову или сочетанию слов". Может, это имел в виду Shamov, говоря о связанных союзах.

Comment: @Ларf теоряи частиц - одна из самых молодых  в современных описаниях грамматики (моложе только "категория состояния"). Еще Ожегов половину частиц относил к наречиям и собзам. Ничего удивительного, что до чих пор нет однозначности вообще. 

Но я во всем этом познавательном (без иронии) тектсе не вижу ответа на вопрос "как в других случаях" или хотя бы "о разграничении союзов и частиц". Можно ли, следуя Н. А. Широковой, назвать частицу "словно" сранительной? Да хоть горшком, частицей она от того быть не сперестанет.

Comment: Я имел в виду то, что одни те же слова могут играть роль как союзов, так и частиц. И определить это можно только по тому, насколько тесно они связаны со сказуемым. Ща чуток подправлю ответ.

Comment: Уже поправили? Лучше не стало. 
Вы плаваете не только в терминологии, но и в самом понятии "термин".
Не "называют" союзы частицами. Ни в каком случае. Это разные вещи. Их **разганичивают**, следуя их грамматической роли в предложении. 
Shamov, нк прекратите, наконец, фантазировать.

Comment: behemothus! Я думаю, в приведенном примере это частица и по Широковой тоже. А меня в связи с этим интересует сравнительные слова между подлежащим и сказуемым. Тоже разнобой в определении.

 Shamov! Я не очень поняла Вашу мысль про сказуемое. А если слово никакого отношения к сказуемому не имеет, то это уже и не частица?

Comment: Хуже того. По всем признакам оно не является частицей даже тогда, когда связано со сказуемым. Оно - всё ещё союз. Но просто удобно называть его частицей, чтобы не путаться с запятыми. Это одно из грёбаных исключений. Если слово выглядит как союз, но при этом связано со сказуемым по смыслу, то не выделяется запятыми, как будто бы это частица.

Comment: >А меня в связи с этим интересует сравнительные слова между подлежащим и сказуемым.  

Не понял. Что такое "слова между..."? Даже предположить не могу... "Находящиеся между"? А "сравнительные слова"?

Ладно, а при чем тут вообще некая (мистическая не иначе) связь частицй с членвми предложения?

Comment: Про связь со сказуемым я тоже ничего не поняла. А я имела в виду предложения типа "озеро как зеркало". А "слова" употребила, объединив частицу с союзом.

Comment: В данном случае это будет сравнительный союз, но запятая не нужна в силу исключения. Я в свой ответ добавил крутейшее правило, которое очень легко запомнить.

Comment: Это не правило, это прием, причем известный ,вытекающий из определения союза и частицы. И я согласна, что это союз.  И тем не менее встречала и мнение, что это частица.

Comment: >А я имела в виду предложения типа "озеро как зеркало". А "слова" употребила, объединив частицу с союзом.  
А! Вы про разраничение... Но это вопрос изначально неблагодарный. Первое, что обычно сообщают учебники про частицу, это то, что у неё почти всегда есть признаки других частей речи - союзов, наречий и проч. Меня вполне устраивает признак "соединительности" ("двуместности отношения", как сказали бы математики) у союза и "одноместности" у частицы. Союз связывает два объекта, частица модифицирует (уточняет, усиливает, изменятет) один. Тут я целиком поддерживаю.

Answer (score 0):

Частица. Большинство словарей, правда, хараетеризует как разговорную.

Answer (score -1):

Сравнительный союз. Аналог "как будто".

**UPD:** Хотел ещё добавить про то, что в данном случае этот союз тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым. И сразу же хотел процитировать правило на этот счёт, в котором сказано, что тесно связанные союзы запятыми не выделяются. Полез за правилом, и выяснилось, что те слова, которые обычно выполняют роль сравнительных союзов, иногда бывают тесно связаны по смыслу со сказуемым, и в этом случае называются частицами. Так что правильный ответ - частица.

**UPD2:** Нашел удобное правило, позволяющее отличать частицы от союзов:

> Попробуйте вычленить интересующее вас
> слово из фразы и посмотреть на
> результат. Если убрать союз, то
> предложение либо его части окажутся
> несогласованными друг с другом
> (например, в этом предложении уберите
> «либо»). Вычленение же частицы в
> большинстве случаев не приведет к
> подобной проблеме согласования
> (попробуйте убрать здесь частицу
> «же»). Также, если вы уберете частицу,
> смысл фразы может поменяться на
> противоположный (в случае с частицами
> «не», «вовсе не», «вряд ли» и т.п.).

Comment: Можно источник такого обязывающего утверждения насчет связанных союзов?

Вообще-то
>Части́ца — служебная часть речи, которая вносит различные значения, эмоциональные оттенки в предложение или служит для образования форм слова.Служебные слова, выражающие главным образом дополнительные смысловые оттенки предложений, словосочетаний, отдельных слов (По Д.Э.Розенталю).  

(Вики)

У меня нет оснований возражать против этого определения.

Comment: В связанном случае они называются частицами.

Comment: Понятно. Очередная фантазия.

Comment: Можно, я здесь допишу? На этот "неблагодарный вопрос" учителям приходится искать четкий ответ. Возражения умного ребенка: если союз, то какой? Подчинительный? Между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Comment: @Ларf Сравнительный. Между подлежащим и сказуемым такой союз вполне уместен (см. ваш же пример про зеркальное озеро).

Comment: @Ларf, вопрос конечно интересный. 

Я прежде всего вынужден извиниться, за "одноместный союз", не предупредил, в математике это понимают не как объект, располагающийся в одном (соответственно - двух местах), а в предикативной троактовке, т.н. - как объект, связывающий один (соответвенно - два) объекта. С этой оговоркой отвечаю по сути.

Comment: Все разговоры про соединительность (двуместность) союза нужны, когда речь идет о разраничении (дифференциации) союза и частицы. Во фразе "озеро как зеркало" этот вопрос не слишком актуален. Здесь "как" явно не частица (семантики такой у частицы нет), а союз, который, однако, не связывает подлежащее со сказуемым, а только располакается между ними, относясь только в сказуемому: c учетом опкуенного глагола-связки: "Озеро [было/есть] как зеркало". В таком случае (и только таком случае) допустиво, видимо, понимание союза как одноместного оператора (относится только к последующему объекту).