# "Его словно не учили этому в школе."

Tags: синтаксис

Запуталась: скажите, пожалуйста, что выражается в этом предложении - сравнение или предположение?

> Его словно не учили этому в школе.

Спасибо!

Comment: Удивительно, но вопрос оказался непростым даже для носителей языка.  Ответы разные, поэтому хотелось бы, чтобы участники форума высказали свое мнение не только голосованием. И еще мне кажется, что эмоции (иногда не самые добрые) стали на форуме  как-то отодвигать истину на второй план. Вот насколько обоснованно был поставлен минус за один из ответов, в то время как решение вопроса, как я считаю,  остается до сих пор дискуссионным и далеко не  ясным.

Comment: *И еще мне кажется, что эмоции (иногда не самые добрые) стали на форуме как-то отодвигать истину на второй план* - здесь это всегда было, удивительно, что вы только сейчас об этом заговорили. Но проблема тут в другом. Истину все понимают по-разному. Для меня Истина - ответ на конкретный вопрос, а не пространные рассуждения, из которых ответ не следует. А если вопрос неконкретен, то там и про Истину говорить не приходится.

Comment: [Этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/9253/183462) может быть Вам полезен.

Comment: @behemothus Истина - это объективно правильный ответ на вопрос, соответствующий современному уровню развития лингвистической науки.  Истинное утверждение  должно быть доказано, исходя из грамматических основ  языка,  с учетом принятых определений, оно должно быть убедительно построено по законам логики и т.д.  А если всего этого нет и я без особых раздумий жму на кнопочку для голосования, то это не поиск истины, а что-то другое.

Comment: *Истина - это объективно правильный ответ на вопрос* Я столько не выпью... Давайте так, или мы без вообще без этой философии обходимся, или даем определение по Канту или по Аристотелю (я предпочитаю второго -conformitas seu adaequatio intentionalis intellectus cum re). Но лучше вообще не надо, ибо не формат для этого форума.

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае "словно" используется для внесения дополнительных смысловых оттенков неуверенности, **предположения**.

Его **словно** не учили этому в школе.

Его **как будто** не учили этому в школе.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ изменен.

***Его словно не учили этому в школе.***

Это сравнение, как я думаю, можно отнести **к ироническим высказываниям.**

**Предложение, вероятно, выражает следующее (для точного определения нужен контекст):** Хотя он учился в школе, но так плохо знает тему, словно его вовсе этому не учили (нейтральный стиль).

**Используя художественный прием иронии,** мы имеем возможность **сократить** тест до одного короткого предложениям и при этом  дополнительно в**ыразить свои эмоции** (удивления, недоумения).

**Рассмотрим другой вариант.**

***Возможно, его просто не учили этому в школе.***

В этом случае выражено именно **предположение** в прямом (не ироническом) смысле. **Разговорная частица "словно" здесь не слишком уместна,** так как она может обозначать сравнение, которого здесь нет. (Сравнение – это худож. прием при описании действительности, а здесь речь идет о самой действительности).

Из словаря

СЛОВНО, I. союз. (**в сравнит. оборотах и сравнит. придат. предл.**). Как, точно, будто. Крадётся, с. кошка. Несётся, с. угорелый. Смотрит, с. сыч. // Употр. для выражения **условно-предположительного сравнения в значении:** как будто, как если бы. Мотор урчит, с. сердится. Ты с. с луны свалился.

**II. частица.** Разг. Указывает **на неуверенность, предположительность высказывания;** как будто. Ты с. чем-то огорчён? Меня с. знобит. Он с. что-то сказал?

Comment: А я вообще не вижу здесь иронии. То есть она может присутствовать, но без должного контекста говорить о ней не приходится. см. примеры в моем ответе.

Comment: Иронический смысл  определяется по контексту, в этом я не сомневаюсь.  Но ирония, если она существует, строится на сравнении:  Он ничего не знает, он ведет себя так, словно никогда не учился в школе. При этом в школе он точно учился, это известно.  Сравнение - это худ. прием, а предположение - это действительность. Предположение чаще заменяется словами "возможно,  наверное", оно реже встречается, это разгов.стиль.  В  школьной теме сложно увидеть предположение вида "меня словно знобит".  Но все   увидели (6 голосов ЗА). Обычное же сравнение  (нейтр. стиль) в текстах явно преобладает.

Comment: Sharon, очень много слов - и не по сути. Если смысл определяется по контексту, значит утверждать, что он там не только есть, но и предопределяет семантику неверно. Остальное к моему замечению отношения не имеет.

Comment: Вы моей главной мысли не увидели. Предположение непосредственно относится к действительности, а сравнение - это худ. прием для описания этой действительности, между ними ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНАЯ РАЗНИЦА.. Например: (1)Ты словно (кажется) огорчен? - (2) Ты так огорчен, будто целое состояние потерял. Коротко: Ты словно целое состояние потерял. И про школу понятно.  Сам строй фразы говорит за себя. (1) Его, кажется, не учили этому в школе (это предположение, здесь союз/частица  словно вообще не подходит). (2) Он ничего не знает, словно его не не учили этому в школе. Здесь сравнение "учили словно не учили".

Comment: Поэтому в заданном предложении не разговорная частица "словно", а нейтральный сравнительный союз "словно". Другими словами, ответ с 6-ю голосами неверен, а правильный ответ получит минус один голос. Как это объяснить? Впрочем, это мое личное мнение.

Comment: *Как это объяснить?* — Вот [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/9253/183462) дано неплохое объяснение. Я думаю, что большинство участников руководствуется той же логикой. Не знаю, правда, изменил ли @behemothus свою точку зрения на тот вопрос. Конечно, если добавить определённый контекст и, заодно, функцию соединения, тогда ситуация однозначно разрешится в пользу союза (и в том вопросе тоже).

Answer (score 2):

> Запуталась: скажите, пожалуйста, что выражается в этом предложении -
>   сравнение или предположение?

И то и другое возможно. Здесь у фразы смысловая неоднозначность, отсюда и все вопросы.

Грамматика фразы позволяет трактовать и так и эдак (иногда говорят о чем-то наподобие семантико-синтакчсической омонимии, но я не хочу употреблять здесь этот не совсем удачный термин), тут впору говорить, чего во фразе больше, а это без контекcта сказать трудно, но скорее всего есть и то и другое.

Варианты:

~1 **Автор знает**, что героя в школе учили. Это **сравнение**. Предположение может возникнуть на уровне а "вот так могло бы быть, если бы не учили в школе". Это случай довольно любопытен, попробую разобраться детально.

~2 **Автор не знает**, чему там учили. Вот тут **предположение** в чистом виде, но фраза немного странно звучит без "бы" в этом случае, лучше - "словно **бы** не учили". Впрочем, по теме вопроса тут все понятно, это явное предположение, семантика сравнения не очень правдоподобна.

Откуда берется разночтение в первом случае?! 
Видимо, определяется отношением к тому, к чему больше относится слово "словно". 
Если к "этому"  (*Петя сказал, что не умеет работать на компьютере, - его словно не учили этому в школе*), то **предположение**.
Если же к самому поведению героя (*Петя охотно изучает основы работы на компьютере,  его словно не учили этому в школе*), то тут субъективно напрашивается сравнение.

Вот как-то так. 
Хотелось ответить по своим ощущениям, до чтения других ответов. Мысли в результате не совсем причесаны, но суть, надеюсь, понятна.

Answer (score 0):

> [СЛОВНО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%9E), I. союз. (в сравнит. оборотах и сравнит. придат. предл.). Как, точно, будто. Крадётся, с. кошка. Несётся, с. угорелый. Смотрит, с. сыч. // Употр. для выражения условно-предположительного сравнения в значении: как будто, как если бы. Мотор урчит, с. сердится. Ты с. с луны свалился. II. частица. Разг. Указывает на неуверенность, предположительность высказывания; как будто. Ты с. чем-то огорчён? Меня с. знобит. Он с. что-то сказал? <Словно как, в зн. союза. Разг. Присоединяет сравнительный оборот или сравнительную придаточную часть предложения; точно, как будто. Звук высокий, словно как поёт кто-то.

Его словно не учили этому в школе.

На мой взгляд, здесь *словно* выступает в роли союза (см. пример выше: *Ты с. с луны свалился*). Не предположение, а именно сравнение с неучем.